# Is there any method to replace iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I just meet an important problem as I have a lot of sources from another domain which means if I use iframe, I have to resize all of these contents. But the problem is that I can not modify or insert code to source web page.
Because of these, I would like to ask if there are any other solutions to skip useing iframe?
Tips: I need the entire contents (include images, css and so on) from the url. Not part of the contents.

Comment: I hope the other domain is okay with you using there data.

Comment: Yeah. I am not a hack ((: I hate the customer as they don't want me to modify their code. But if it is really impossible I will negotitate with them

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function might be the best place to start.  Is it just the markup you're unable to change, or are you able to use PHP and JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

Try using `include('http://www.google.com')` to include a URL in your page without using an iFrame.  Any non-absolute directory references in the code (like `<img src='/img.png'>` will not display or load correctly.

If you need to fix up these references and don't have the ability to change the markup itself, you can use the `file_get_contents` function and modify things like this:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$page = preg_replace('/(href|src)=([\'"])\//',"$1=$2http://google.com/",$page);
echo $page;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just can not resize the content of the iframe because it is from another domain. And the most important is that I can not modify the source page. So that I want to replace the iframe. Could you give me more info or like some sample code. Thanks

Comment: By the way, it is not a php file, it is a certain url such as http://www.google.com

Comment: You can include URLs with PHP's include function.  Try `include "http://www.google.com";`.  If it doesn't work, you might need to modify your php.ini file's `allow_url_include` variable.

If you need to modify the contents of the page displayed at the URL, you can use PHP's [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function and modify the returned data.

Comment: @beanland thanks you answer helped me a lot! especially with links issue.

Answer (score 1):

Quick idea - you could try to write a proxy on server side and serve the content in the iframe, but with src pointing to the proxy page instead of the real page (i.e. controlled with passed parameters)

Comment: Thanks a lot. In this way, I still have to change something in the source page. But as this project. it is impossible to do that. Is that any other solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your needs. What changes in source page will require the solution with proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX call using the JSONP data type to return the contents of the other page.  You would need to make modifications to the code on both domains though to make this work.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 0):

Modified answer of @beanland, my **/proxy.php** file, with caching:

```
$host = parse_url($_GET['url'], PHP_URL_HOST);
$dir  = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/cache_proxy/'.$host;
if(!is_dir($dir))
    mkdir($dir);
$filepath = $dir.'/'.md5($_GET['url']);

if(is_file($filepath)){
    include($filepath);

}else{
    $page = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);

    $page = preg_replace('/(a href)=[\'\"](http.*)[\'\"]/', '$1="http://buy/proxy.php?url=$2"', $page);
    $page = preg_replace('/(a href)=[\'"][^http](.*)[\'"]/', '$1="http://buy/proxy.php?url=http://'.$host.'/$2"', $page);
    $page = preg_replace('/(href|src)=[\'"][^http+](.*)[\'"]/', '$1="http://'.$host.'/$2"', $page);

    file_put_contents($filepath, $page);

    echo $page;
}
```

First replace all `<a href="">` links to your proxy, then replace all relative `<img src="/path...">` etc. to absolute `<img src="http://...">`

Answer (score -1):

jQuery Load into a div http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Other domain - so unless it is using CORS, not possible

Comment: yeah. That is the most hard part for me to deal with. I am thinking not use javascript, instead I want to think about use PHP curl, for example, to slove it.

Comment: Yes, make a proxy and include the files on the server.